# Use of whispers/whispering

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

> As the terrorist walked off, whispers started among the hostages.
> As the terrorist walked off, the hostages started whispering.

1. Are "whispers" and "whispering" used correctly in the two sentences?
2. Do they mean approximately the same?
3. Which one of the sentences would be more common? Does one sound more formal than the other?

Answer (score 1):

> As the terrorist walked off, whispers started among the hostages.

This means that gossip or rumours started.

**Example**
A: I think that guard might accept a bribe!

B: Next time he comes around, I'll sound him out.

---

> As the terrorist walked off, the hostages started whispering.

They started talking very quietly in whispers.

Comment: I would also like to add that “whispering” is a verb and “whispers” is a noun (in this context), so they don’t quite mean “the same thing,” to clarify.